# EventID 1 - An application or system component changed the time

Tags: windows-server-2016, ntp, time-synchronization

Our VM's are coming up with the following errors in the Event Log -

EventID 1 Change Reason: An application or system component changed the time.

All the DC's look to be time synced correctly, but we are also getting this error on the PDC -

Root PDC is not Syncing from NTP Server.

Issue
If you do not configure the PDC to synchronize time from an external or internal time source, the PDC emulator uses its internal clock and is itself the reliable time source for the forest. If time is not accurate on the PDC itself, all computers will have incorrect time settings.

Fix
1.On the affected Domain Controller, open a command prompt.
2.Stop the Time service: net stop w32time
3.Configure the external time source: w32tm /config /manualpeerlist: time.windows.com /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes 
Note: Replace time.windows.com with the address of your desired external time source.
4.Start the Time service: net start w32time

The time is synced with the Windows Time NTP service, but we get the following error when running the w32tm configuration command -

C:\Windows\system32>w32tm /query /configuration
The following error occurred: The interface is unknown. (0x800706B5)

Comment: Are the VM's synchronizing time with the host?

Comment: No, they aren't.

Comment: What does `w32tm /monitor` say on a domain logged on machine?

Comment: Ended up decommissioning the DC.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up decommissioning the DC.